# Indexing array and putting contents into TextBox

Tags: arrays, excel, textbox, vba

I have an array made of strings that I am trying to loop through and put the contents into a `Textbox`. Unfortunately, my program overwrites the previous line each time it adds another element of the array, failing to skip a line. Any ideas?

Note: The `textbox` is called `NotesBox`. The `userform` that the `textbox` is on is called `TabData`

```
For v = 1 To counter_notes - 1
    TabData.NotesBox.Text = ProdNotes(v) & Chr(13)
Next v
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an array directly to the `.List` property of a `ListBox`, like:

```
TabData.NotesBox.List = ProdNotes
```

Otherwise, you don't assign to the `.Text` property, you could use the `.AddItem` method in a loop:

```
Dim itm
For each itm in ProdNotes
    TabData.NotesBox.AddItem itm
Next
```

If you are using a `TextBox`, then use the `VBA.Join` function like so:

```
TabData.NotesBox.Text = VBA.Join(ProdNotes, Chr(13))
```

Or, in a loop:

```
With TabData.NotesBox
    For i = LBound(ProdNotes) to UBound(ProdNotes)
        .Text = .Text & ProdNotes(i) & Chr(13)
    Next
End With
```

Comment: I would like to use a textbox for text-wrapping properties.

Comment: @Liz your question said "ListBox" -- these are two different things. I'll revise my answer though...

Comment: @Liz see revised answer :)

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!